# Retornar valores PHP via Ajax e exibir no HTML (separadamente)

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, banco-de-dados

tem como retornar valores de uma página  PHP via Ajax e exibi-los separadamente?
Ex.:
Eu tenho uma página PHP no qual eu tenho os valores de retorno:

```
<?php
 echo $a;
 echo $b;
 echo $c;
?>
```

Atualmente eu consigo determinar via Jquery que eles sejam exibidos em uma determinada DIV, só que todos aparecem juntos (no mesmo lugar). Eu gostaria de saber se teria como eu determinar que "$a" vai ser exibida em uma determinada DIV, e as demais variáveis em outras DIV. Tem como?

A minha finalidade é: Acessar o banco de dados, trazer valores e setar em uma modal. Atualmente eu já consigo chamar essa MODAL e preencher o BODY dela com os dados do servidor. Porém, eu não quero exibir esses valores apenas no BODY. Eu preciso exibir $a no HEADER, $b no BODY e $c no FOOTER desta MODAL.

Tem como fazer exatamente isso?

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Porque vc não coloca seu código na pergunta? Assim daria menos trabalho a quem se interessar em lhe ajudar além de lhe devolver uma resposta ajustada no seu próprio código.

Answer (score 1):

Como você está trabalhando com JavaScript tente retornar sua resposta do PHP em formato JSON para o AJAX:

```
<?php
    echo json_encode(
        "a" => "1",
        "b" => "2",
        "c" => "3",
    ));
?>
```

E agora você pode trabalhar com este retorno da seguinte forma:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'seu-arquivo-php',
    success : function(data) {
        var json = $.parseJSON(data)[0];
        var a = json.a;
        var b = json.b;
        var c = json.c;

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No php, coloquei em uma array as 3 variaveis(a,b,c),no js da pra saber pelo indice qual é, variavel A é indice = 0,assim por diante. Feito isso voce vai conseguir exibir cada uma separadamente.

```
<?php
// echo $a;
// echo $b;
// echo $c;
   $arr = [$a,$b,$c];
   echo (json_encode ($arr));
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    method:'post',
    url: 'taa.php',
    async: true,
     dataType:'json',
    success: function (arr) {
        var a = arr[0];
        var b = arr[1];
        var c = arr[2];
    }


});
```

Comment: Meu amigo, sua resposta me ajudou muito, porém ainda não obtive êxito. Acredito que pode ser algo relacionado ao comando ECHO em um ARRAY, como ele não converte ele não consegue passar os parâmetros. Tentei com PRINT_R mas nada acontece também. Poderia me ajudar por favor?

Comment: boa observação, código corrigido.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, mas ainda continuando não exibindo os valores. Fiz o teste tanto com: document.write(a); " como também $("#a").append(a); e nenhum deles exibe o valor.

Comment: voce alterou o ajax para sua url (    url: 'taa.php', ) ? fiz testes e não ocorreu nenhum problema.

Comment: taa.php ? Não! Eu mantive minha UL ( url: 'servidor.php',). Como você exibiu os valores em seus testes ?

Comment: js : https://jsfiddle.net/goqhfsng/  php : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b5a9c416ab36b63f273de41997ffebba743ec2e4

Comment: Estranho, esse que você postou também não está funcionando aqui... obs: minhas variáveis PHP são strings e inteiros e minha função jquery é chamado por um botão: $("button").click  isso pode interferir no resultado final ?

Comment: abre o console do seu navegador, verifica se ele chega a fazer alguma requisição pro seu arquivo .php

Comment: Nada amigão. Eu acabei encontrando uma alternativa paliativa. No arquivo PHP eu peguei o ARRAY e utilizei a função IMPLODE para passar os valores pela URL como string: $txt = implode("|", $vetor); No ajax eu usei o dataType como HTML, normal mesmo: dataType: "html" e dei um SPLIT na string que veio no parâmetro da UL: array = result.split("|"); Aí depois foi só exibir o que eu queria: em array[0], array[1], array[2]... Como eu disse essa foi uma forma paliativa, que já atende meu problema. Mas eu realmente gostaria de entender o problema com JSON, pois já precisei outras vezes e não deu.